# Get path to all referenced Assemblies from external Assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, assemblies

I'm attempting to create a method which allows the user to select any assembly. Running this will then show all the paths to the referenced assemblies within this selected assembly.

I first create a new AppDomain and use the ResolveEventHandler.

I then get the assemblyPath from the selected assembly using *OpenFileDialog*:

```
Assembly selectedAssembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
AssemblyName[] assemblyNames = selectedAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();

foreach (AssemblyName assembly in assemblyNames)
    {
        Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.Load(assembly);
        string assemblyLocation = currentAssembly.Location;
    }
```

The problem is, only assemblies which are referenced in the current project can be found and therefore loaded.

Is there any way to get the path of all of the referenced assemblies from a selected dll?

Comment: what do you mean by get the path of all of referenced assemblies from selected dll

Comment: Using .GetReferencedAssemblies() on an assembly will return an array of AssemblyName: e.g. mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089. I would like the fully qualified path to this reference, the assembly resolver will attempt to find this assembly by looking in the GAC, but cannot always be found